# simple jquery trigger help

Tags: jquery, triggers

I have two icons, when I click first icon I want to appear some bunch of text somewhere on the website and when I click 2nd icon the text from the 1st icon  to disappear automatically.
Thanks.

Comment: And what is the question? What do you have problems with? What have you tried? Have a look at [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<img src="http://img.vmessages.com/icon/dogs/61.gif" id="show" />
<img src="http://img.vmessages.com/icon/dogs/65.gif" id="hide" />
<div id="textDiv">This is the div with some text</div>

$('#textDiv').hide();

$('img#show').click(function(){
    $('#textDiv').show();    
});

$('img#hide').click(function(){
    $('#textDiv').hide();    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/AQgv8/

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you have 2 icons and you want to insert/remove the text on `MyDiv`.

So the we are binding the click event on the icon. (icons names are `1stIcon`, `2ndIcon`)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // First Icon Click
  $('#1stIcon').bind('click', function(){
    $('#MyDiv').val('SOME TEXT');
  });

  // Second Icon Click    
  $('#2ndIcon').bind('click', function(){
    $('#MyDiv').val('');
  });

});
```

Comment: To make it work should use .text() instead of .val(). Also ids starting with letter are illegal I believe.